# detailtextlabel set to nil

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, null, detailtextlabel

I have `UITableViewCell` cells with `style = UITableViewCellStyleValue1` (this style is used in all other `view controllers` that I use in my project). I've double checked the `cell identifiers` in my storyboard as per suggestions from other SO posts. Still I get `detailTextLabel` as nil. Is there something else I am doing wrong ? I observed that the cells are always reused i.e if statement for allocation is never executed. So, how do I get my `UITableViewCell` object's style to verify that the reused cells follow the same style ?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellForDevice";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     }
     NSLog(@"reuse ID : %@",cell.reuseIdentifier);
     // Configure the cell...
     NSArray* row = [self.listOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     NSString* str = [row objectAtIndex:0];
     NSString* status = [row objectAtIndex:1];
     cell.textLabel.text = str;

     if(cell.detailTextLabel == nil) 
        NSLog(@"detailTextLabel nil");//didn't expect this would execute

     cell.detailTextLabel.text = status;
     cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
     NSLog(@"status %@ ",status);
     return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the cell as prototype cell in your storyboard file? In that case the cell is always loaded from the storyboard and you should check the properties of the prototype cell.

Comment: OK, great. I have added my comment as formal answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a cell is defined as prototype cell for the table view in a storyboard file,
`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` always instantiates cell as necessary from the
storyboard file. In particular, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` never return `nil`.

You should therefore check the properties of the prototype cell and you can remove the
`if (cell == nil)` part from your code.